# How can I speed up my node mempool to fetching pendding tx faster

Tags: txpool

My node seems too slow to get pending transaction and broadcast my transaction. Is there some way to speed up?

Comment: What do you mean by slow ? Why do you say it is slow ? What do you mean by "speed up" ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain It my fault not clear the question. I do some arbitrage from different DEX. The process is getting pending tx and do some local calculation and then send the arb tx to the chain. I found that even my local calculation spend only 1ms I still behind some other competitors(On BSC chain, the same gas price and no MEV things, order by arrival time). So I think it my node slow then others when fetch pending tx or broadcast tx. Thank you for any suggestions ：）